# Trying to pass a contentcontrol tag/title as argument in a VBA function

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to create a function that put a contentcontrol box content's into clipboard by pressing a button.

So far I managed to do it manually by creating a sub for each button that ties the button to a contentcontrol text box by title. See code below

```
Private Sub DemandeAvec_Click()
                    Dim obj As New DataObject
                        Role = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Rôle")(1).Range.Text
                        PusleDemande = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Demande")(1).Range.Text
                        obj.SetText Role & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & PusleDemande
                        obj.PutInClipboard
                  
                End Sub
```

The problem is that i'm trying to automate it by creating a function that is called when pressing any button, by passing the name of the contentcontrol box it is tied to by using its title as an argument in the function.

In the code below, the argument in question in named "PulseName".

```
Function ClicBoutonRole(PulseName As String) As String
                    Dim result As New DataObject
                    Dim PulseFinder
                    Role = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Rôle")(1).Range.Text
                    PulseContent = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("**PulseName**")(1).Range.Text
                    result.SetText Role & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & PulseContent
                    result.PutInClipboard
                    
End Function


*Button named ModificationsSCAvec_Click

Sub ModificationsSCAvec_Click() 
        Dim PulseName As String
        PulseName = ModificationsSC 
*ModificationsSC being the title of the content control box I'm trying to link to the button
        ClicBoutonRole (PulseName)

*Trying to pass the tag of the contentcontrolbox by calling the function with PulseName as the argument of the function.

End Sub
```

I got to say I'm really new to VBA, so I'm fully aware this code is wrong in many ways.

Each time I click the button, word gives me the code 5941, member of collection doesn't exist.

I'm sorry if my english is not perfect, as I'm not a native english speaker.

My question is the following ? What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you have several problems with your code, but you are getting error #5941 because the line `ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("**PulseName**")(1).Range.Text` does not find a ContentControl.

You need to pass the parameter `PulseName` to `SelectContentControlsByTitle`, now you are passing the string `"**PulseName**"`.

Also, in the code that calls `ClicBoutonRole` you need to pass the string with the title of the ContentControl, now you are passing the ContentControl-object itself.

Final tip, put `Option Explicit` at the top of your code module, and the compiler will not let you run code without making sure all the variable names are correct, you have a few of those errors in there as well.

Try something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Function ClicBoutonRole(PulseName As String) As String
    Dim result As New DataObject
    Dim Role As String
    Dim PulseContent As String
    
    Role = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Rôle")(1).Range.Text
    PulseContent = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle(PulseName)(1).Range.Text
    result.SetText Role & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & PulseContent
    result.PutInClipboard
End Function


Sub ModificationsSCAvec_Click()
    ClicBoutonRole ("ModificationsSC")
End Sub
```